# Access model instance from model field

Tags: django, django-models

I want my Django custom model field to set an attribute on the model instance.

I'm sure it's not working this way but here is an example:

```
class MyField(models.Field):
    __metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        model_instance = ????
        setattr(model_instance, "extra_attribute", "It's working!")

class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_field = MyField()

model_instance = MyModel.objects.get(pk=123)
print model_instance.extra_attribute # output: "It's working!"
```

Django's ForeignKey model field is doing a similar thing, so it is possible :P
I think ForeignKey field is using the contribute_to_class method.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a special Proxy class that will replace the field. When getting or setting field value, you can use 'obj' attribute to access model instance. See this example:

```
class ObjectField(models.PositiveSmallIntegerField):
    class ObjectProxy:
        def __init__(self, field):
            self.field = field

        def __get__(self, obj, model):
            if obj is None:
                return self.field  # this is required for initializing model field

            value = obj.__dict__[self.field.name]  # get actual field value
            # ... here you can do something with value and model instance ("obj")

            return value

        def __set__(self, obj, value):
            # same here
            obj.__dict__[self.field.name] = value

    def contribute_to_class(self, cls, name):
        super().contribute_to_class(cls, name)
        # set up our proxy instead of usual field
        setattr(cls, name, ObjectField.ObjectProxy(self))
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not have access to the model instance from inside your `Field` object, sorry. Django's `ForeignKey` accomplishes the `foo_id` thing by having separate `name` and `attname` fields, but the actual setting of `foo_id = 123` is done the same way as all the other model fields, [deep in the QuerySet code](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/db/models/query.py?rev=17600#L1369), without interacting with the field classes.

And conceptually, what you're trying to do is a bad idea - action-at-a-distance. What if adding a particular field could cause bugs in unrelated model functionality, say, if an attribute another field was expecting got overridden? It would be difficult to debug, to say the least. I don't know what your underlying goal is, but it should probably be done in model code, not a field class.

Here's a `ModelField` that does what you want:

https://gist.github.com/1987190

That's actually pretty old (like maybe pre-1.0, don't remember now), had to dust it off a bit - I'm not sure if it still works. But it's definitely doable, hopefullly this gives you an idea.

Comment: I'm trying make a field that support a relation to any model (like GenericForeignKey but in one field). It will save "%d.%d" % (model_type, instance.pk) to a charfield. The field's attname will be "%s_guid" % name ( = model_instance.my_field_guid). I want to hit the DB and serve the related instance when model_instance.my_field is called ( like Foreignkey is doing ). Thank you

Comment: Oh, well that's easy :). I thought you meant setting arbitrary other fields. I'll update with an example of the "ModelField" I have sitting around.

Comment: The to_python method runs for all fields when a model instance is created right? I want to convert the charfield value to the right type of object only when this specific field is called. Just like ForeignKey field does. I think this is what makes the trick for ForeignKey fields: https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/db/models/fields/related.py#L980 But I have not been able to replicate it. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

**init** is called when Django processes the Model Class, not the Model Instance. So, you can add the attribute to the Model Class (e.g. by using 'add_to_class' http://www.alrond.com/en/2008/may/03/monkey-patching-in-django/ ). To add the attribute to the instance you should override the **init** of the instance (but I think this is not your case).

Comment: No, init is called as the last step in object construction.

Comment: @Marcin: Thanks, I probably have misunderstood the actual flow. Can you post some documentation about it?

Comment: Wow, Marcin, you're kind of an asshole. He's clearly talking about the Django ORM code path, which isn't remotely trivial.

Comment: And for the record, Don, you have it right - `Field.__init__` is called at module-import time, and is never called during model instantiation.

Comment: @AdamKG: It's far from obvious that a reader should mentally insert the words "Field" and "Model" into the first sentence. Also, to be exact, `Field.__init__` is called at class creation time where those `Field` properties are declared in the body of the class, which may be later than module import time; it will happen later if you somehow manage to hack a working django model that creates `Field`s later.

Answer (score -5):

How about

```
model_instance = SomeExtraModel.objects.get(pk=1456)
```

replacing `1456` with something that makes sense

Comment: This makes an extra query to database, that is inefficient.